# Migrating react-icons from 2.2.7 to 4.10.1

Tags: reactjs, icons, react-icons

#### I am migrating my code base from react-icons version 2.2.7 to 4.10.1 and I have so many imports like -

```
react-icons/lib/io/android-locate
react-icons/lib/io/chevron-right
```

#### Is there a method to find these icons with the existing ones, or do I have to do it manually all one by one?

#### Any help would be appreciated

currenly we have to it manually by seraching each icons and reciewing the designs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.